# A modern and extensible C++14 logger

Tags: c++, c++14, logging, template-meta-programming

I recently wrote this C++ Logger API code for a game engine. It needs to be as fast as possible so I tried to postpone everything to compile-time using different template meta-programming tricks (for instance, [`static_if`](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2015/07/simulate-static_if-with-c11c14.html)).
Any advice, bug fixes or suggestions are welcome.

**Log.h:**

```
// Copyright(c) Matyas Yves Constans 2016-2017
#ifndef CIANADE_LOG_H
#define CIANADE_LOG_H

#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

namespace cnd
{

    /** @brief Specifies the minimum log level.
     * Enumeration specifying the minimum
     * log level at which LogEntry will
     * write a message to a stream.
     * @see LogEntry
     */
    enum class LogLevel
    {
        FATAL, /// < Indicated that the application cannot go on (lowest log level)
        ERROR, /// < Indicates that an error has occured
        WARN, /// < Indicates that the application has issued a warning
        INFO, /// < Indicates that the corresponding message gives some kind of information to the end-user
        DEBUG, /// < Indicates that the corresponding message is targeted to developpers / modders / etc...

        DEBUG_1, /// < Indicates that this message must be differentiated from different debug levels
        DEBUG_2, /// < Indicates that this message must be differentiated from different debug levels
        DEBUG_3, /// < Indicates that this message must be differentiated from different debug levels
        DEBUG_4, /// < Indicates that this message must be differentiated from different debug levels (highest log level)
    };

    /** @brief Represents a Log entry, that can be modified and written to different streams.
     * An entry will be written to a specific stream when
     * an instance is destroyed, if the entry's logging level is higher
     * the reporing level. The default reporting level is LogLevel::DEBUG
     * Note that you should use one of the log printing
     * functions/macros instead to print messages.
     * @tparam T specifies which io stream to use.
     * @see LogLevel
     */
    template <typename T>
    class LogEntry
    {
    public:
        /** @brief Constructor.
         */
        LogEntry();

        /** @brief Prints current message.
         * Prints a formatted message based on the internal stream's content.
         */
        virtual ~LogEntry();

        /** @brief Returns a reference to the instance's stream.
         * Returns a reference to the stream so a message can be printed using the
         * standard c++ stream syntax.
         * Shall be overridden when inheriting from LogEntry
         * @tparam Level Specifies the log level corresponding to the message
         * @return The stream corresponding to the log entry
         */
        template <LogLevel level>
        std::ostringstream& GetMessageStream();

        /** @brief Returns the current logging level.
         * @return The Current logging level (The default log level is LogLevel::DEBUG).
         * @see LogLevel
         */
        constexpr static LogLevel GetReportingLevel();

    public:
        /** @brief Converts an std::string to a LogLevel
         * @param level An std::string representing a LogLevel. it can be either "FATAL",
         * "ERROR", "WARN", "INFO", "DEBUG", "DEBUG_1", "DEBUG_2", "DEBUG_3" or
         * "DEBUG_4".
         * @return The corresponding log level.
         */
        static LogLevel StringToLogLevel(const std::string& level); // runtime

        /** @brief Converts a LogLevel to an std::string.
         *
         * The return values can be either "ERROR", "WARN", "INFO", "DEBUG", "DEBUG_1", "DEBUG_2", "DEBUG_3"
         * or "DEBUG_4".
         * @tparam Level LogLevel that needs to be converted
         * @return The Converted std::string
         */
        template <LogLevel level>
        constexpr static std::string LogLevelToString(); // compile time

        template <LogLevel level>
        constexpr static unsigned int LogLevelToEnumIndex(); // compile time
    public:

        /** @brief Instances are non assignable! */
        LogEntry& operator=(const LogEntry& obj) = delete;
        /** @brief Instances are non assignable! */
        LogEntry(const LogEntry& obj) = delete;

    protected:
        /** @brief String stream used to output the final message.
         * Should be used to output a custom message when inheriting
         * from LogEntry.
         */
        std::ostringstream outputSStream_;

    private:
    };

    //TODO add documentation!
    class LogStream_Generic
    {
    public:
        static const FILE* GetStream();
        static void SetStream(FILE* stream);
        static void Output(const std::string& msg);
    private:
        static FILE* stream_;
    };

    template <LogLevel level = LogLevel::DEBUG>
    void WriteLog_Generic(const std::string& msg);

    template <LogLevel level = LogLevel::DEBUG>
    void WriteLog(const std::string& msg);

    #define CIANADE_LOG_STREAM(logLevel)\
        if (cnd::LogEntry<cnd::LogStream_Generic>::LogLevelToEnumIndex<logLevel>() > /* (probably) compile time */\
        cnd::LogEntry<cnd::LogStream_Generic>::LogLevelToEnumIndex<cnd::LogEntry<cnd::LogStream_Generic>::GetReportingLevel()>());\
        else cnd::LogEntry<cnd::LogStream_Generic>().GetMessageStream<logLevel>()
}

#include "Cianade/System/Details/Log_details.h"
#endif //CIANADE_LOG_H
```

**Log_details.h:** (implementation)

```
// Copyright(c) Matyas Yves Constans 2016-2017
// @file Log_details.h - 12/23/2016

#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include "../Time.h"
#include "../StaticIf.h"

template <typename T>
cnd::LogEntry<T>::LogEntry() = default;

template <typename T>
cnd::LogEntry<T>::~LogEntry()
{
    outputSStream_ << "\n" << std::flush;
    T().Output(outputSStream_.str());
}

template <typename T>
template <cnd::LogLevel level>
constexpr std::string cnd::LogEntry<T>::LogLevelToString()
{
    return level == LogLevel::FATAL ? "FATAL" : // compile time
            ( level == LogLevel::ERROR ? "ERROR" :
            ( level == LogLevel::WARN ? "WARN" : 
            ( level == LogLevel::INFO ? "INFO" : 
            ( level == LogLevel::DEBUG ? "DEBUG" : 
            ( level == LogLevel::DEBUG_1 ? "DEBUG_1" : 
            ( level == LogLevel::DEBUG_2 ? "DEBUG_2" : 
            ( level == LogLevel::DEBUG_3 ? "DEBUG_3" : 
            ( level == LogLevel::DEBUG_4 ? "DEBUG_4" : 
            "" /* Should never happen, unless enum is extended*/
            ))))))));
}

template <typename T>
template <cnd::LogLevel level>
constexpr unsigned int cnd::LogEntry<T>::LogLevelToEnumIndex()
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<cnd::LogLevel>>(level);
}

template <typename T>
cnd::LogLevel cnd::LogEntry<T>::StringToLogLevel(const std::string& level)
{
    switch (level)
    {
        case "INFO":
            return LogLevel::INFO;
        case "WARN":
            return LogLevel::WARN;
        case "DEBUG":
            return LogLevel::DEBUG;
        case "ERROR":
            return LogLevel::ERROR;
        case "FATAL":
            return LogLevel::FATAL;
        case "DEBUG_1":
            return LogLevel::DEBUG_1;
        case "DEBUG_2":
            return LogLevel::DEBUG_2;
        case "DEBUG_3":
            return LogLevel::DEBUG_3;
        case "DEBUG_4":
            return LogLevel::DEBUG_4;
        default:
            return "";
    }
}

template <typename T>
template <cnd::LogLevel level>
std::ostringstream& cnd::LogEntry<T>::GetMessageStream()
{
    outputSStream_ << "- " << time::GetCurrentTimestamp();
    outputSStream_ << " " << LogLevelToString<level>() << ": ";
    return outputSStream_;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr cnd::LogLevel cnd::LogEntry<T>::GetReportingLevel()
{
#ifndef CIANADE_MAX_LOGLEVEL
    return LogLevel::DEBUG;
#else
    return CIANADE_MAX_LOGLEVEL;
#endif
}


FILE * cnd::LogStream_Generic::stream_ = stdout;

const FILE* cnd::LogStream_Generic::GetStream()
{
    return stream_;
}

void cnd::LogStream_Generic::SetStream(FILE* stream)
{
    stream_ = stream;
}

void cnd::LogStream_Generic::Output(const std::string &msg)
{
    if (!stream_)
        return;
    fprintf(stream_, "%s", msg.c_str());
    fflush(stream_);
}

template <cnd::LogLevel L>
void cnd::WriteLog_Generic(const std::string& msg)
{
    constexpr unsigned int current_level 
            = LogEntry<LogStream_Generic>::LogLevelToEnumIndex<L>();
    constexpr unsigned int max_level 
            = LogEntry<LogStream_Generic>::LogLevelToEnumIndex<LogEntry<LogStream_Generic>::GetReportingLevel()>();
    constexpr bool condition = current_level <= max_level;

    staticIf<condition>([&](auto f){ // compile time
        LogEntry<LogStream_Generic>().GetMessageStream<L>() << msg;
    });
}

template <cnd::LogLevel level>
void cnd::WriteLog(const std::string& msg) { WriteLog_Generic<level>(msg); }
```

**main.cpp** (example)

```
#define CIANADE_MAX_LOGLEVEL cnd::LogLevel::DEBUG
#include <Cianade/System/Log.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cnd::WriteLog<cnd::LogLevel::DEBUG>("Hello -.-"); // puts syntax
    CIANADE_LOG_STREAM(cnd::LogLevel::INFO) << "Hello ^-^"; // stream syntax

    cnd::WriteLog<cnd::LogLevel::DEBUG_2>("nope"); // not displayed
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the most obvious issue.

```
cnd::WriteLog<cnd::LogLevel::DEBUG>(getMessage("BLa", "Bla", 5));
```

If the log level `DEBUG` is not going to print anything. Then calling the function `getMessage()` is a complete waste of time. You need to defer the call of `getMessage()` and only call it when it will generate something useful.

#### Bad Code:

This is not even legal C++

```
cnd::LogLevel cnd::LogEntry<T>::StringToLogLevel(const std::string& level)
{
    switch (level)  // level must be an integer type
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't even notice that it was not valid code! It's weird that gcc/msvc didn't even complain or issue a warning. Also can you give me an example about deferring the call to "getMessage()" ?

Comment: @MattMatt templates are not actually compiled until they are instantiated. So this just means you don't use that part of the code.